# Android added circle indicator to viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Hi i have created a view pager but does anyone know how i can show circles that represent pagination on a page view i think its clued an indicator but i'm not entirely sure?

heres the code so far that contains my view pager

```
public class LevelSelect extends Activity {

    private ViewPager awesomePager;
    private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 10;
    private Context cxt;
    private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_levelselect);
        cxt = this;

        awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter();
        awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
    }

    private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

            LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View LeagueButtonView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ls_button, null);
            Button LeagueButton = (Button) LeagueButtonView.findViewById(R.id.league);
            LeagueButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ls_level_eng1_locked));
            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(LeagueButtonView,0);

            return LeagueButtonView;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
        }



        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view==((View)object);
        }


        @Override
        public void finishUpdate(View arg0) {}


        @Override
        public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1) {}

        @Override
        public Parcelable saveState() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void startUpdate(View arg0) {}

    }
```

Comment: Your answer is right [here](http://viewpagerindicator.com/). There is a project sample with all you need to know. Feel free to ask for some help if you still need it.

Comment: you can create dots with textview and use the timer to highlight the respective dots based on change of page in viewpager,  See the full code here http://codesfor.in/android-viewpager-slider-with-indicator/

Answer (score 14):

You can use Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator to add the titles  or simple circles for each tab in your ViewPager.

Jake Wharton has supplied a bunch of sample code on [GitHub](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), you can also refer to the [usage section](http://viewpagerindicator.com/#usage) on the Jake Wharton's site.

[image]

You can also use the ViewPager and PageIndicator of [Greendroid library](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid)

[image]

Comment: where did you get the first screenshot from? Did you implement it yourself? If so, do you have a sample code for it? Thanks :D

Comment: @KalaJ I this it's from [the library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) which is mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Take two image(circle or any other shape image one for  off another for on). Take one frame layout, show the image(indicator)  on frame.When user change the image show the proper indicator.

I have implemented this and working fine. You can [download](http://javaant.com/viewpager-with-circle-indicator-in-android/#.VpZ1McB943g) the code and change accordingly.
[image]

Comment: Upvoting because this works. There are simpler answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots