# Android ViewPager with bottom dots

Tags: android, user-interface, android-viewpager, android-fragmentactivity, viewpagerindicator

I want to add 3 bottom dots to my ViewPager, like this.

[image: 3 bottom dots]
[image: 3 bottom dots]
[image: 3 bottom dots]

I use FragmentActivity and support library ViewPager.

Comment: I need to add dots, not tabs (like Nexus 5 launcher).

Comment: Check out my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38459310/4631935

Answer (score 408, accepted):

**Pager bottom dots/indicators in Compose**

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun PageIndicator(
    count: Int,
    pagerState: PagerState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        repeat(count) { index ->

            // play with size and corner shape to get the desired result
            // following displays a dot
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(16.dp)
                    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(50))
                    .background(
                        if (pagerState.currentPage == index) selectedColour else normalColour
                    )
            )

            // to add space between indicators
            if (index != count) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 4.dp))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*That's it :) Compose is love :D*

### **Previous answer for ViewPager**

**No need for that much code.**

You can do all this stuff without coding so much by using only **`viewpager`** with **`tablayout`**.

**Your main Layout:**

```xml
<RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
       android:id="@+id/tabDots"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
       app:tabGravity="center"
       app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hook up your UI elements in activity or fragment as follows:

**Java Code:**

```java
mImageViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDots);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mImageViewPager, true);
```

That's it, you are good to go.

You will need to create the following xml resource file in the **drawable** folder.

**tab_indicator_selected.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="4dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
</shape>
```

**tab_indicator_default.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="oval"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
    </shape>
```

**tab_selector.xml**

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
          android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/>
</selector>
```

Feeling as lazy as I am? Well, all the above code is converted into a library!
**Usage**
Add the following in your gradle:
`implementation 'com.chabbal:slidingdotsplash:1.0.2'`
Add the following to your Activity or Fragment layout.

```xml
<com.chabbal.slidingdotsplash.SlidingSplashView
        android:id="@+id/splash"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:imageResources="@array/img_id_arr"/>
```

Create an integer array in `strings.xml` e.g.

```xml
<integer-array name="img_id_arr">
   <item>@drawable/img1</item>
   <item>@drawable/img2</item>
   <item>@drawable/img3</item>
   <item>@drawable/img4</item>
</integer-array>
```

*Done!*
**Extra** in order to listen page changes use `addOnPageChangeListener(listener);`
Github [link](https://github.com/Chabbal/slidingdotsplash).

Comment: Does this spread the dots across the whole parent width? You'd want the dots to be 10-20 dp apart for a page indicator.

Comment: it places the dots in the center of the parent width....and yes appropriate spacing is also there between the dots...up vote if it helped you..

Comment: This solution, and most of the others, adds a ViewGroup and an extra View for each page, which is unnecessary waste to draw a few circles. I went with Jake Wharton's library, but added his code directly so I could fix some small issues.

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but the array going into the strings file can't find @Drawable/img 1-4. These are not mentioned here. What am I missing???

Comment: hi you have to create your own array in strings.xml. and add those images  mentioned in array to drawable folder...by the way 'd' of your @Drawable/img is Capital make it small...

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it is working fine! but how do we detect which position we're at ? I need to know which position of tha pager we're at so I can update other views.
I tried the setOnShowImageListener and tried to work with that call back, but it doesn't get called. Can you please advise ?

Comment: i have updated the answer change version of library in gradle and use onPageChangeListener...

Comment: I had already upvoted before I ask the question, because it already helped me a lot, but now I wish I can apvote +2 or +100 :) because adding the onPageChangeListener worked perfectly for me!
And just to make it clear for anyone that may use this, you need to do your updates on the onPageSelected callback only, adding the update in the onPageScrolled callback makes it messy, it starts the update as soon as you start scrolling, which is not visually good!

Comment: Why do we need a TabLayout?

Comment: You can just use `shape` as the root element for the indicator drawables. There's no need to wrap them as individual items in a `layer-list`.

Comment: Can someone help me? I used the library and the sliding dot is visible but whenever I slide the image it doesn't move the sliding dot. In other words, if I slide the image from the corner then it will slide the image but not the sliding dot, and If I slide from the middle, it will slide the dots but not the image. I have images in my fragment and viewpager in activity_main.xml. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :).  @Juni

Comment: kindly post your question with your code on github repository so that i can look into it.

Comment: Nice solution that works great. However this doesn't work if you override `GetPageTitleFormatted` as you will end up with tabs with titles and dots.

Comment: any way to reduce the space between the dots?

Comment: @Juni how will i show left side page, mid page , next page using same example with dots indicating to page 1

Comment: Works perfectly `Xamarin.Android`. great answer.

Comment: Is it possible to change the colour of dots? like white fill dots when selected and not-fill when unselected?

Comment: yes change the respective indicator drawable.xml to your needs, it should work then

Comment: For recycler view? page indicator?

Comment: You want to use `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` in newer Versions

Comment: Update: that works but you should use new components:  androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager and com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout

Comment: the dots don't seem to slide along with the page. I use the slidingsplashview

Comment: The above drawable XML looks weird until I changed shape to `ring`. Seems like ring is also used in the slidingdotsplash library instead of oval.

Comment: @katie It was originally "ring" but someone revised it to "oval". (And perhaps I approved the edit without reading it). Thanks for pointing out

Comment: How is it possible to animate dots when pages are scrolling?

Comment: @M.Afrashteh You can add your own code in ```onPageScrolled``` to move the dots...or if you don't wanna do it yourself then use a library that does this

Comment: This solution can be somewhat simplified. No need of the extra `tab_selector.xml`. 
 See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69392018/5284698)

Answer (score 43):

My handmade solution:

In the layout:

```xml
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dots"
        />
```

And in the Activity

```
private final static int NUM_PAGES = 5;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private List<ImageView> dots;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    addDots();
}

public void addDots() {
    dots = new ArrayList<>();
    LinearLayout dotsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.dots);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        ImageView dot = new ImageView(this);
        dot.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pager_dot_not_selected));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        dotsLayout.addView(dot, params);

        dots.add(dot);
    }

    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            selectDot(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
}

public void selectDot(int idx) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        int drawableId = (i==idx)?(R.drawable.pager_dot_selected):(R.drawable.pager_dot_not_selected);
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(drawableId);
        dots.get(i).setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use heavy component `Layout` just to put a dot? Use `View` instead.

Comment: I think the linear layout is so that it will center and group the dots.

Answer (score 37):

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                switch (position) {
    case 0:
        img_page1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_selected);
        img_page2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page3.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page4.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        break;

    case 1:
        img_page1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_selected);
        img_page3.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page4.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        break;

    case 2:
        img_page1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page3.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_selected);
        img_page4.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        break;

    case 3:
        img_page1.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page3.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot);
        img_page4.setImageResource(R.drawable.dot_selected);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: `setOnPageChangedListener()` deprecated!! Use `addOnPageChangedListener()` now.

Comment: This is not really a great solution, as you have to know exactly how many pages you'll be using. As soon as you add or remove a page, you're in trouble.

Comment: Don't fight the framework. Android has tools for doing this as TabLayout, there is no reason for reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Simplify to this:           private void setDotSelection(int index) {
                dot1.setImageResource(index == 0 ? R.drawable.circle_selected : R.drawable.circle);
                dot2.setImageResource(index == 1 ? R.drawable.circle_selected : R.drawable.circle);
                dot3.setImageResource(index == 2 ? R.drawable.circle_selected : R.drawable.circle);
                dot4.setImageResource(index == 3 ? R.drawable.circle_selected : R.drawable.circle);
                dot5.setImageResource(index == 4 ? R.drawable.circle_selected : R.drawable.circle);
            }

Answer (score 33):

I created a library to address the need for a page indicator in a ViewPager. My library contains a View called DotIndicator. To use my library, add `compile 'com.matthew-tamlin:sliding-intro-screen:3.2.0'` to your gradle build file.

The View can be added to your layout by adding the following:

```
    <com.matthewtamlin.sliding_intro_screen_library.indicators.DotIndicator
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:numberOfDots=YOUR_INT_HERE
            app:selectedDotIndex=YOUR_INT_HERE/>
```

The above code perfectly replicates the functionality of the dots on the Google Launcher homescreen, however if you want to further customise it then the following attributes can be added:

- `app:unselectedDotDiameter` and `app:selectedDotDiameter` to set the diameters of the dots
- `app:unselectedDotColor` and `app:selectedDotColor` to set the colors of the dots
- `app:spacingBetweenDots` to change the distance between the dots
- `app:dotTransitionDuration` to set the time for animating the change from small to big (and back)

Additionally, the view can be created programatically using:

```
DotIndicator indicator = new DotIndicator(context);
```

Methods exist to modify the properties, similar to the attributes. To update the indicator to show a different page as selected, just call method `indicator.setSelectedItem(int, true)` from inside `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(int)`.

Here's an example of it in use:

[image]

If you're interested, the library was actually designed to make intro screens like the one shown in the above gif.

Github source available here: https://github.com/MatthewTamlin/SlidingIntroScreen

Comment: Got error at indicator.setSelectedItem(position, true);  IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Which version? I thought I fixed that in 3.0.1, also what were your values for indicator.size() and position?

Comment: Great library! However, is there a more elegant way to update selectedItem and numberOfItems at the same time? Depending on which one is bigger, the order changes, otherwise you throw an IndexOutOfBounds exception. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vincesp/cbd6e77210ced924ac4368288c9826bb).

Comment: @vsp DotIndicator implements the SelectionIndicator interface, which means if has two useful methods which can solve your problem: `int getNumberOfItems()` and `void setNumberOfItems()`. Rather than catching the exception, you could do something like this https://gist.github.com/MatthewTamlin/761c7338d271af29526edc7859480aef.

Comment: For anyone not following the gist conversation, there was actually a bug which has now been fixed. 3.0.2 is the latest version as of right now.

Comment: How to use DotIndicator class in the Activity? it says cannot resolve symbol  DotIndicator

Comment: @zakusha sounds like it's probably an IDE error, have you tried cleaning and rebuilding he project? I've had problems with Android Studio just not finding classes that are definitely in the dependencies before. As a worst case solution, try invalidating your cache and redownloading all dependencies. Still, I'll check there's nothing wrong with the library and get back to you.

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to use this library?

Comment: in mine dots, transition is not happening

Answer (score 24):

`ViewPagerIndicator` has not been updated since 2012 and got several bugs that were never fixed.

I finally found an alternative with this light library that displays nice dots for the `viewpager`, here is the link:

https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator

Easy to implement!

Comment: What bugs do you know? Can you provide some sources?

Comment: Both of these are ring shape xml drawable.
yet i see rectangular boxes as seperator.

 app:ci_drawable=. "@drawable/selected_dot"
                app:ci_drawable_unselected=. "@drawable/default_dot"

Comment: easy to impliment, but it shows rectengular box in selected case even though i have set circuler xmls only.

Answer (score 20):

I thought of posting a simpler solution for the above problem and indicator numbers can be dynamically changed with only changing one variable value `dotCounts=x` what I did goes like this.

1. Create an xml file in drawable folder for page selected indicator named "item_selected".

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
        android:dither="true">
        <size android:height="8dp" android:width="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/image_item_selected_for_dots"/>
    </shape>
```

2. Create one more xml file for unselected indicator named "item_unselected"

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
        android:dither="true">
        <size android:height="8dp" android:width="8dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/image_item_unselected_for_dots"/>
    </shape>
```

3. Now add this part of the code at the place where you want to display the indicators for example below `viewPager` in your Layout XML file.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/banner_pager"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

4. Add this function on top of your activity file where your layout is inflated or the above xml file is related to

```
    private int dotsCount = 5;    //No of tabs or images
    private ImageView[] dots;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    
    private void drawPageSelectionIndicators(int mPosition){
        if(linearLayout!=null) {
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
        }
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);
        dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i] = new ImageView(context);
            if(i==mPosition)
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_selected));
            else
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.item_unselected));
    
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
    
            params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);
            linearLayout.addView(dots[i], params);
        }
    }
```

5. Finally in your onCreate method add  the following code to reference your layout and handle pageselected positions

```
    drawPageSelectionIndicators(0);
    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            drawPageSelectionIndicators(position);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

Following is my proposed solution.

- Since we need to show only some images in the view pagers so have avoided the cumbersome use of fragments.

  - Implemented the view page indicators (the bottom dots without any extra library or plugin)
  - On the touch of the view page indicators(the dots) also the page navigation is happening.
  - Please don"t forget to add your own images in the resources.
  - Feel free to comment and improve upon it.

A) Following is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="schneider.carouseladventure.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerCountDots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

B) pager_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

C) MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    int[] mResources = {R.drawable.nature1, R.drawable.nature2, R.drawable.nature3, R.drawable.nature4,
            R.drawable.nature5, R.drawable.nature6
    };

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    private CustomPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private LinearLayout pager_indicator;
    private int dotsCount;
    private ImageView[] dots;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager_indicator = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);
        mAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, mResources);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

        setPageViewIndicator();

    }

    private void setPageViewIndicator() {

        Log.d("###setPageViewIndicator", " : called");
        dotsCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotsCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            params.setMargins(4, 0, 4, 0);

            final int presentPosition = i;
            dots[presentPosition].setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(presentPosition);
                    return true;
                }

            });


            pager_indicator.addView(dots[i], params);
        }

        dots[0].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        Log.d("###onPageSelected, pos ", String.valueOf(position));
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nonselecteditem_dot));
        }

        dots[position].setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selecteditem_dot));

        if (position + 1 == dotsCount) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

D) CustomPagerAdapter.java

```
 import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
        private int[] mResources;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] resources) {
            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mResources = resources;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item,container,false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
           /* LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(950, 950);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
            container.addView(itemView);
            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
            collection.removeView((View) view);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mResources.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == object;
        }
    }
```

E) selecteditem_dot.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">

    <size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>

    <solid android:color="#7e7e7e"/>
</shape>
```

F) nonselecteditem_dot.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
        android:dither="true">        
        <size android:height="12dip" android:width="12dip"/>        
        <solid android:color="#d3d3d3"/>
    </shape>
```

[image: first image]

[image]

Comment: i used this but on viewpager scroll dots are not changing

Comment: this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

The solution provided by [@Junaid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40047719/5284698) can be simplified.
Instead of creating a selector (`tab_selector.xml`) you can simply set the drawables on the `TabLayout` directly.

```xml
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="<youColor>"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="8dp" />
```

`app:tabIndicatorHeight` is set to the same value as in `tab_indicator_selected.xml`.
Following this approach you keep the default animation of the `TabLayout`.
Programmatically, you have to set the tab as selected:

```kotlin
object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        val tab = binding.tabLayout.getTabAt(position)
        binding.tabLayout.selectTab(tab, true)
    }
}
```

Please note that I used `ViewPager2`. There should be equivalent method using `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to build a `viewPager` with thumbnails as indicators, using this library could be an option:
**[ThumbIndicator](https://github.com/mahdimoqadasi/ThumbIndicator) for viewPager that works also with image links as resources.**

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did this, somewhat similar to the solutions above. Just make sure you call the *loadDots()* method *after all images are downloaded*.

```
    private int dotsCount;
    private TextView dotsTextView[];

    private void setupAdapter() {
        adapter = new SomeAdapter(getContext(), images);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
    }

    private final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++)
                dotsTextView[i].setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

            dotsTextView[position].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    };

    protected void loadDots() {
        dotsCount = adapter.getCount();
        dotsTextView = new TextView[dotsCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dotsTextView[i] = new TextView(getContext());
            dotsTextView[i].setText(R.string.dot);
            dotsTextView[i].setTextSize(45);
            dotsTextView[i].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            dotsTextView[i].setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GRAY);
            mDotsLayout.addView(dotsTextView[i]);
        }
        dotsTextView[0].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

XML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="#00000000"/>


    <ImageView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/introImageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/image_count"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
</FrameLayout>
```