# Android swipe: Initial tutorial in an app

Tags: android, initialization, swipe, slide

I'm trying to do an initial tutorial in my app like in this image:

[image: the init tutorial that I'm trying to do]

Do you know the name of this feature? In order to find a tutorial for it.

Comment: You can accomplish this using a ViewPager, and the bottom part can be done with a library such as http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Thanks @bastien-caudan but the look is a little older

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two things

- ViewPager
- Custom ViewPager indicator - draw circles in canvas

You will be updating the indicator like this

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onPageSelected(int position) {
     // Update your custom view
  }

  @Override
  public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, ViewPager. I do not know how to use canvas yet. I do this tutorial for viewPager indicator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented by using custom `ViewPager` or `ViewPager Adapter` you have to check if item is last available and bring user to the main application. Or you can use library. This library [Android WizardPager](https://github.com/romannurik/android-wizardpager) by  **romannurik**  pretended to be what are you looking for.

If you are looking for only `ViewPagerIndicator` there is another great library [Android ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator). There are a lot of examples provided there.

You can some examples of using indicators in sample application available for downloading in Maven Repository [ViewPagerIndicator Maven Repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.viewpagerindicator/sample/2.4.1)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the viewpager is what I was looking for