# How to achieve image sliding option with page indicator like play store image slider in home page?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

How to achieve image sliding option with page indicator like play store image slider in home page?. I want to achieve the paging indication as same as play store does it home page of play store app . Please find the screenshot for the same .

[image]

I don't think Android will go private libraries . I want to use the same what google has used to develop for the same .

Comment: this is simple view pager which add in listview or recyclerview ....

Comment: Please read my question i need page indicator as same above in screenshot

Comment: dude this is not a big task just you need to make radio group view and use accordingly ...

Comment: or you make dynamically layout for achieve your task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some search I believe all you need is [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

The dot page indicator could be the page number of drawables. When new page is selected, `onPageSelected` is called and in there you can set which dot should be enlarged (or replace the drawable with a larger dot) to indicate the current page.

Here is a similar question with some other way of implementation:
[Android ViewPager with bottom dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots)