# How to import ViewPagerIndicator in android studio?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I want to use ViewPagerIndicator in my app. So I need its library. I find these 2 links for downloading, [Link1](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator) and [Link2](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

But I don't know how can I add it to my project?

this is my build gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "standup.maxsoft.com.standup"
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}
```

I just copy 2 files in `libs.folder`. Would you please help me steplly? Thanks

Comment: Here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTaIQ0LMLy0 and https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: @ErenUtku. How about using it in android studio?

Comment: Did you check the second link?

Comment: this is very complete.But indicator part is not complete.  it says general information about it. I need to use circle in my view pager header.

Comment: I suggest evrtone who want easy and suitable solution, look and check this answer:http://stackoverflow.com/a/40047719/3671748

Answer (score 1):

You can use this dependency (it's an analog):

```
compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1@aar'
```

Comment: I do it, but it shows this: `Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not download library.aar (com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1)
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/library-2.4.1.aar'.
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/viewpagerindicator/library/2.4.1/library-2.4.1.aar'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused`