# How do i achieve this sort of swipe navigation

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

I have a grid layout containing multiple linear layouts. Each linear layout contains an image view and a text view. Currently all the images and their description appear on the screen but i want to create a swipe functionality which will make another set of images appear when the user swipe the screen. I want to create something just like this

[what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yh4w6.png)

Here is my xml file

```
  <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="facility_click"
            android:id="@+id/layout_facility1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/fridge1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fridge"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="facility_click"
            android:id="@+id/layout_facility2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/alarmclock" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alarm clock"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="facility_click"
            android:id="@+id/layout_facility3"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image3"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/dishwasher1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dish washer"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:onClick="facility_click"
            android:id="@+id/layout_facility4"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image4"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/fridge1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fridge"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/fridge1"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fridge"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/alarmclock" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Alarm clock"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/dishwasher1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dish washer"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/fridge1" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Fridge"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you need ViewPager:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Each "grid" will be separate fragment.

EDIT:

Also see this: it seems very simmilar to what you want to get:
[Android ViewPager with bottom dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots)

Comment: thanks @muminers. i checked the link you sent and i'm using the post that was marked as answer for my solution but having created each grid as fragments i dont know where to hook it up with the viewpager. Can you help me out on this

Comment: If I understood you correctly you are asking about FragmentPagerAdapter. So here you will find good tutorial: https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter and also source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Comment: hi @munimers. i had to do extra researches but your answer was a starting point for me. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a RecycleView adapter and a cardView along with it....it is quite easy as compared to all the other methods. Just don't forget to add both RecycleView and cardView dependencies in you build.gradle

Comment: RecycleView is like a listView....you don't have to worry about swipe....unlike listView it can make horizontal swipes as well.