# Displaying One or Multiple Photos in post like Instagram

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am creating a ***photo blog app*** using `firebase`. I am able to allow user to post one or multiple photos on the `firebase` database and I am also able to retrieve them successfully.

[image: Example]

Above image is the bottom view of an instagram post.

Just like that I want some type of `View` or `Layout`. I already have a working layout which can show only one image with like, comment and share options.

If the user wants post one photo, the layout should show just one slide and if user wants to post multiple photos, it should create a so called `Sliding View` to display all images side by side.

How do I do this ?

If you want me to clarify anything in more detail, please let me know.

Comment: You can use ViewPager with indicator, Please try to Search before asking question directly as View Pager is very well known widget in Android development, This tutorial will help you http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/  also here is useful answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486218/android-added-circle-indicator-to-viewpager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android ViewPager with bottom dots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586619/android-viewpager-with-bottom-dots)

Comment: why don't you use ViewPager with Page Indicator hide it if your image array size = 1

Answer (score 4):

If you need to build something similar that you mentioned then take example from the following library.

[View Pager Indicator](https://github.com/ktoso/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

You need to use `ViewPager` along with `CirclePageIndicator` mentioned in the library.

`ViewPager` - images container
`CirclePageIndicator` - circle indicator

You will need to add another overlapping view, which will contain like, comments and other buttons.

Comment: @Amolppskamble Thanks for the help ! I am going to try this today and then tell you what happened !